# Show java.time.LocalDateTime using jstl

Tags: java, jsp-tags

JSTL Format does not support java 8 LocalDateTime. Is there anyway to format the LocalDate/Time to a string on a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing a nuance in your question, but could you not do something like:

`<%= LocalDateTime.now().toString() %>` ?

You can replace `.now()` by another instance of LocalDateTime, and `.toString()` by `.format(...)`, if you want a specific date time formatted in a specific way.

Comment: I was looking to avoid scriplets and avoid having to create my own tld.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

`request.setAttribute("formatter",formatter.format(LocalDateTime.of(2018, 3, 30, 10, 0)));`
//-------jstl in jsp :-------------

```
${formatter  }
// or :
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%> <br>
  <fmt:parseDate value="${ item.localdateTime}" pattern="y-M-dd'T'H:m" var="myParseDate"></fmt:parseDate> 
<fmt:formatDate value="${myParseDate}"  pattern="yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm"></fmt:formatDate >
```